# In SwiftUI creating buttons as per different cases

Tags: swiftui, closures

I have swiftUI scene for Error.
That error can be uses for Network , login etc anything.
Buttons and their actions on that screen varies as per the errortype.

```
    enum ErrorItem: String {
        case subscriptionError = "Subscription"
        case networkError = "NetworkError"
    }

init(errorType: ErrorItem) {
        super.init()
        if errorType == ErrorItem.subscriptionError {
            titleString = "Login Error"
            numOfButton = 1 // I do not want to use this . I want to create some closure and enum of buttons and create array of buttons
        }
        else {
            titleString = "Something Went Wrong"
            numOfButton = 2
        }
    }
```

I am handling number of buttons display by "numofButtons".
But for each case number of buttons, their titles and their actions will also be different.
What are the best approach to handle that ?

Can i create something like this and have array of ErrorButtonTypes. So if one screen contain 2 buttons i.e close and action button i can use both and if one screen contain 1button only close button i can use only 1 button

```
enum ErrorButtonType {
case close(String) // String = title
case action(String, (() -> Void) // String = title, function = action to take with that button
}
```

Comment: It would be a little more common to use a `switch` statement rather than `if/else`, but besides that it's pretty hard to say unless you show more about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy and efficient way to declare var inside the enum and set value for each case. Like this

```
enum ErrorItem: String {
    case subscriptionError = "Subscription"
    case networkError = "NetworkError"
    
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .subscriptionError:
            return "Login Error"
            
        case .networkError:
            return "Something Went Wrong"
        }
    }
    
    var numOfButton: Int {
        switch self {
        case .subscriptionError:
            return 1
            
        case .networkError:
            return 2
        }
    }
}
```

And your init is

```
init(errorType: ErrorItem) {
    super.init()
    titleString = errorType.title
    numOfButton = errorType.numOfButton
}
```

---

---

**EDIT**

As per your edited question, you can use enum with action like this.
Your enum

```
enum ErrorButtonType {
    case close(String) // String = title
    case action(String, (() -> Void)) // String = title, function = action to take with that button
}
```

Declare your enum

```
var errorType: ErrorButtonType = ErrorButtonType.close("Close")
```

set enum value

```
let action: (() -> Void) = {
     // Your button action
}
errorType = ErrorButtonType.action("Action", action)
```

Get enum value

```
switch errorType {
case .close(let title):
    print(title)

case .action(let title, let action):
    print(title)
    action() // Assign this action to button
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was awesome